# Problems with autocompletetextview editing result

Tags: java, android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I am relatively new to programming and currently I want to have an 'auto-complete text view' that a user filled in earlier, to influence the final text result. I thought that I would be able to do a simple 'if' function string, but that doesn't seem to work as apparently it needs an 'expression' expected, a Boolean or a string. To be honest, I am struggling to figure out what exactly I need to write - whether I need ot define the textbox function itself etc. - which I guess is why I am having this issue.

Here is what I have so far:

(in mainactivity.java)

```
 package com.example.danielsaleh.myapplication;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.w3c.dom.Text;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    // In order for us to have the text-view display and change according to what the person clicked in the textbox, we need an Array list, which is done below
        ArrayList<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();
        TextView final_text;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final_text =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.final_answer);
            final_text.setEnabled(false);

            changeTextOnce();




            // This is the code to find the string variable
            String[] Exam_Board;


            // We need a text view here
            autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.exam);
            // We need to get the string array here in order to make the auto-complete (linked to strings.xml), so we do the below code
            Exam_Board = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.exam_board);
            // We need some place to store the text, following the previous comment. The way to do this is by storing the 'array' which is done as below
            ArrayAdapter<String> exam = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Exam_Board);
            // Now we need to set the view from the string, which is from the adapter. The name entitled in this case is 'exam' so we use the 'setadapter' method and type exam
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(exam);
```

And then: (this is where my problem is). The code above is the auto-complete text view

public void changeTextOnce() {

```
final TextView changingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changingtext);
Button changeTextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butto);

changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if () {

        }
        changingText.setText("The answer is.....");

    }
```

The if () is where the problem is..as I seemingly cannot fix this!

The actual string code concerned:

```
 <string-array name="exam_board">

        <item>CIE</item>
        <item>EDEXCEL</item>
        <item>OCR</item>
        <item>AQA</item>

    </string-array>
```

And if it is needed (though I think that it is not needed tbh..but I am nowhere near experienced enough to tell myself that!). The activity.main file is:

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exam"
        android:hint="Type of Exam Board"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/changingtext"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/topic"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/butto"
    android:layout_below="@+id/butto" />
```

It is worth noting that the { errors are just because I am omitting parts of the code that is not concerned in my problem, because otherwise this post would be so large it would be absolutely ridiculous for anyone to even answer my question!

Thanks and have a good weekend!

Comment: `if ()` must have an expression to evaluate inside the brackets. What exactly is that if used for, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I want to do is 'if' the auto-text view (so the person types in) let's say CIE, the textbox called changing text will respond accordingly, in a different way to let's say someone wrote EDEXCEL. I just wrote (), because my problem is I do not know how to format what is needed.

Comment: How about using a `switch-case` or adding a TextWatcher on your EditText?

Comment: I realise I must somehow define WHICH autotextbox (there are two in my actual coding), and then somehow input that result into the coding, which is my ultimate problem

Comment: How woud lI go about doing that?xD Sorry, I have used a switch-case before but never a TextWatcher..and not in the way that you are saying

Comment: Well just use `.getText().toString()` and compare that text to some values. TextWatchers is just a fancy listener that gets triggered whenever a new character is typed in in any EditText.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot move this to a chat! Do I need to create a specific string then? or just write if(.getText().toString(). If you could give an example that owudl be great!xD

Comment: I meant `autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString()`. This is how you get a text that's currently written, and then you can compare it in switch-case to the strings you have.

Comment: So if I wrote autoCompleteTextView.getText("CIE").toString(Exam_Board). Then: switch (view.getID()) { case R.id.autoCompleteTextView?. I have only ever used switch case in checkboxes..so I have no clue how to do it for an autocompletetextview..which is why I am asking so many questions!

Comment: I think I understand how to do it now for 1 autoCOmpleteTextView. But in my actual code I have 2 of them! How do I make it so that I can limit the response with an if + switch on both of them at once?..I.e. if someone picked CIE + 2009?